# I want first td value after login to the site

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

**HTML Code:**

```
<table id="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" tabindex="1" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01" style="width: 1053px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto">
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:124px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:149px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:249px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:149px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:99px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:149px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:99px;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;"/>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;"/>
    </tr>
    <tr id="15430" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="15430" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_PK_AuditId">
    <a href="../AuditMGMT/AuditInfo.aspx?Mode=Default&AuditId=15430&RollId=VRContact&ViewAssessment=True">15430</a>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Dante Meds" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_EntityName">Dante Meds</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Due Diligence for Dante Meds Open" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Description">
    <a href="../AuditMGMT/AuditInfo.aspx?Mode=Default&AuditId=15430&RollId=VRContact&ViewAssessment=True">Due Diligence for Dante Meds</a>
    <br/>
    <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;">Open</span>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Vendor Contact" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_AssignedToUser">Vendor Contact</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Vendor Contact" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Role">Vendor Contact</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="04/25/2017" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_AddedOn">04/25/2017</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Open" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Status">Open</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="0" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Cat_Code">0</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="1" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_UserStatus">1</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="VRContact" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_RoleID">VRContact</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="True" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_ViewAssessment">True</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="Open" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_HistoryStatus">Open</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="15429" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-priority-secondary" tabindex="-1" role="row">
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="15429" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_PK_AuditId">
    <a href="../AuditMGMT/AuditInfo.aspx?Mode=Default&AuditId=15429&RollId=VRContact&ViewAssessment=True">15429</a>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Med Corp" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_EntityName">Med Corp</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Due Diligence for Med Corp Pending Due Diligence" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Description">
    <a href="../AuditMGMT/AuditInfo.aspx?Mode=Default&AuditId=15429&RollId=VRContact&ViewAssessment=True">Due Diligence for Med Corp</a>
    <br/>
    <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;">Pending Due Diligence</span>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="LCO or SME" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_AssignedToUser">LCO or SME</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Country Compliance Manager" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Role">Country Compliance Manager</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="04/21/2017" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_AddedOn">04/21/2017</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Open" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Status">Open</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="0" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_Cat_Code">0</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="1" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_UserStatus">1</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="VRContact" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_RoleID">VRContact</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="True" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_ViewAssessment">True</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="Pending Due Diligence" aria-describedby="ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01_HistoryStatus">Pending Due Diligence</td>
    </tr>
```

Like in above HTML, first `<td>` contains value as `15430` so I want to fetch that value.

Note:  - Each time when an entry gets added to the table that value `15430` will be change, incrementally of `+1`. So, the new value first value will be `15431` and so on.

Comment: Can you put a proper heading with all the details within Description area? What are your testing steps? What have you tried so far? Show code. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Share some more info so that everyone can understand the scenario.

Comment: @KrishnaReddy I updated some information and shared image also. can u kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these mentioned code using **xpath locator**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Open']/..//preceding::tr/td[1]/a")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:-**

1) Use `text` method along with `<td>` tag and move ahead with `<tr>` tag using `preceding` keyword.

2) Here I have use `[1]` that represent `indexing number`. Indexing number is always start with 1.

`td[1]` indicates first `<td>` tag.

3) In your all `<td>` tag I found all the records are unique, so i have to target only `open` keyword. because when you make any entry over this table, bydefault status of that entry will be open.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td[1]/a")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01']/..//following::tr[@class='ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr']/td[1]/a")).click();
```

**Note:-** If you get `element not found error`, then provide wait for few seconds before reach this above code.

Comment: thanks for answering. But if an user adds data then current ID will go down and new one will be at the top right. I want to select the link whichever at top of the webtable everytime I execute code. I want to handle dynamic change.

Comment: I have posted my code kindly look into that and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will click link in First row (excluding table header) and First column.The code is in java.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id ='ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01']//tr[contains(@class, 'ui-row-ltr')]/td[1]/a")).click();
```

I hope It will will help

Comment: Good to know that your problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code using cssSelector: it will always click the first row first column element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table#ctl00_pagecontent_ctl01 tr:nth-child(2)>td>a"))).click();
```

Comment: @ jainish Kapadia, Kushal, @shailendra everyone's code worked. thanks for helping me out...